# Multiple File upload with dynamic fields

Tags: php, javascript

Can you please advise/help me with this code? I want to upload multiple files to the server and save the information in database. But this code is uploading only one file, from the first input field.

I have dynamic "upload file" fields, like this:

```
              <form action="uploader.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label>Upload</label>
                <input type="file"  name="file[]">
                <label>Description</label>
                <input type="text" id="filedesc" name="filedesc[]">
                <a href="#" onClick="addUpload('dynamicInputUpload');" >
                <img src="../../img/add.png" ></a>
        <div id="dynamicInputUpload"></div>
 <input type="submit" float= "right"  name="add" id="add" value="UPLOAD" > 
 <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="<?php echo $pid; ?>">
 <input type="hidden" name="intnumber" id="intnumber" value="<?php echo $int; ?>">     
        </form>
```

Bellow is the Javascript that creates dynamic fields:

```
 var counterUpload = 1;
 var limit = 10;
 function addUpload(divName){
 if (counterUpload == limit)  {
      alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counterUpload + " inputs");
 }
 else {
      var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
      newdiv.innerHTML = " <label>File " + (counterUpload + 1) + "</label><input type=\"file\" name=\"file["+counterUpload+"]\" id=\"file["+counterUpload+"]\"> <label>Description " + (counterUpload + 1) + "</label><input type=\"text\" id=\"filedesc["+counterUpload+"]\" name=\"filedesc["+counterUpload+"]\" >"
      document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
      counterUpload++;
 }
```

}

And the problem is bellow in the uploader.php. I suceed to uplaod only one (the first) file.

```
<?php
 include '../../c/config.php';
 include '../../c/opendb.php';
 // Settings
$allowedExtensions = array('jpg','gif','bmp','png', 'docx', 'doc','pdf');
$maxSize = 2097152;
$storageDir = '../uploads/';

// Result arrays
$errors = $output = array();

if (!empty($_FILES['file'])){  

  // Validation loop 
  foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $i=> $value){

  $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
  $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'][$i];
  $fileErr = $_FILES['file']['error'][$i];
  $fileExt = strtolower(pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

  // Validate extension
  if (!in_array($fileExt, $allowedExtensions)) {
    $errors[$fileName][] = "Format $fileExt in file $fileName is not accepted";
  }

  // Validate size
  if ($fileSize > $maxSize) {
    $errors[$fileName][] = "$fileName excedes the maximum file size of $maxSize bytes";
  }

  // Check errors
  if ($fileErr) {
    $errors[$fileName][] = "$fileName uploaded with error code $fileErr";
  }

}

// Handle validation errors here
if (count($errors) > 0) {
  die("Errors validating uploads: ".print_r($errors, TRUE));
}

// Create the storage directory if it doesn't exist
if (!is_dir($storageDir)) {
  if (!mkdir($storageDir, 0755, TRUE)) { 
    die("Unable to create storage directory $storageDir");
  }
}

// File move loop
foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $i=> $array_value){

  // Get base info
  $fileBase = basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
  $fileName = pathinfo($fileBase, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
  $fileExt = pathinfo($fileBase, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $fileTmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];

  // Construct destination path
  $fileDst = $storageDir.'/'.basename($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
  for ($j = 0; file_exists($fileDst); $j++) {
    $fileDst = "$storageDir/$fileName-$j.$fileExt";
  }

  // Move the file    
  if (move_uploaded_file($fileTmp, $fileDst)) {
    $output[$fileBase] = "Stored $fileBase OK";
     $sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO uploaded_files (pid, file_path,file_type)
            Values ('$_POST[pid]','$fileDst','$fileExt')") 
            or die ("Unable to issue query sql: ".mysql_error());
  } else {
    $output[$fileBase] = "Failure while uploading $fileBase!";
    $errors[$fileBase][] = "Failure: Can't move uploaded file $fileBase!";
  }

}
 // Handle file move errors here
if (count($errors) > 0) {
  die("Errors moving uploaded files: ".print_r($errors, TRUE));
} }
```

Comment: Here you will find a good example how to do that: http://techstream.org/Web-Development/PHP/Multiple-File-Upload-with-PHP-and-MySQL

Comment: Thank you. I have seen that, but this examples is for multiple selection in one input field. What I need is multiple Input fields, because I will need to assign a description to each one.

Comment: @Lilou did you got the solution. If so, can you please share. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This string has an error:

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO uploaded_files (pid, file_path,file_type)
Values ('$_POST[pid]','$fileDst','$fileExt')")
or die ("Unable to issue query sql: ".mysql_error());
```

Try to comment this string, your script will save all files.
Maybe you did not connected to the database.

Comment: I made this php-page,and I can check all components except bd-connection, this connection is included from other file.
If I commented insert to database all images would be saved in the upload folder. If the first image is saved in the folder, it means the folder is opened for writting (maybe there is no empty space for uploading other files).
I printed array $_FILES - it stored data all files, in the cycle "foreach($_FILES['file']['name'] as $i=> $array_value)" variables $fileTmp and $fileDst is generated correctly. All says about error is in the database or php-connection to the database.